# Why isn't the proxy server isn’t responding in IE 11?

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet-explorer

I'm having problems with Internet Explorer 11 I'm getting the message;

> The proxy server isn't responding and it won't connect to the
>   Internet.

Firefox works fine but other programs need Internet Explorer to work, like with my Juno email program.

I'm using Windows 7, IE 11. I go through my WiFi, Router, & cable modem to get on the Internet. Using Avast Free Antivirus.

What I have tried:

- When I go into IE, Tools. Internet Options, Connections, LAN
  Settings. It is all grayed out so I can't make any changes in that
  area.
- Have I installed any programs lately to cause this? Well the answer
  seems to be yes but I not sure what I did.
- When I go into Control Panel, Uninstall or change a program I don't
  see and obvious programs that should not be there.
- I go into Internet Explorer manage add-ons and disable everything.
- I have checked my Firewall.

Not sure how to remove Internet Explorer to reinstall it.

What do I need to do to correct this problem?

Comment: This on a corporate network by chance?  Are you using a domain or local user?

Comment: Not on a corporate network, this is my home PC so local user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run complete scans to remove any viruses and malware. These are not the same thing, meaning a single program will not likely clean everything. Use something like Malwarebytes to scan your computer.

Once that is done, if you are still experiencing problems, reset IE 11 by going into options, the Advanced tab and click <kbd>Reset...</kbd> at the bottom under `Reset Internet Explorer settings`.

[image]

Comment: YES!! Why didn't I think  of this?! Great, it now seems to be working. I can access webpages just fine. Thank you @CharlieRB this certainly solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try going to control panel/Internet Options. To see if you can change the settings there.

On the connections tab, click on LAN settings if you can and unselect "Automatically detect settings". This stops IE from checking for a proxy every time you create a new tab.

If you cannot access the settings, the implication is that your PC has some administrator level controls in place. Either your current login does not have local administrator privileges or your PC is part of an enterprise Domain which applies proxy restrictions on you. If this is the case, it has been done badly because the appropriate restrictions haven't also been applied to Firefox. Quite probably, in this case, the issue is because you are not connected to your enterprise network. You will need to contact your IT department to fix their proxy settings.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : Right Click at internet Explorer and run as administer 
Step 2 :Internet Options >Advanced > Click at Reset... > click at "Delete personal settings " Box > Reset
Step 3: Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings > unckeck "Use a proxy server ...." and Click at Automatically detect settings
Step 4 : Firewall security enable